# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method requestPermissions on channel flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter2.0

I have the problem with flutter 2.0 and androidX project, with iOS work fine. I already check all the documentation and issues but no lucky.
I'm working with those libraries in pub spec.yaml:

```
image_picker: 0.7.5+3
permission_handler: ^8.0.0+2
```

the line with the exception:

```
await Permission.photos.request();
```

relevant configs:
gradle propieties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

manifest xml

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true
```

GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:
the plugins are present

I already run flutter clean, flutter run, cold run, but again, no lucky.

any ideas are welcome, regards

Comment: Share a traceback of the Exception

Comment: thank you for your answer, the traceback of the exception: No implementation found for method requestPermissions on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try in terminal,

> flutter clean
>
> flutter run

Stop running the app and kill the app from device/simulator. Then restart the application.

Stop running by clicking button, refer screenshot below,
[image]